# Optimization for Google PageSpeed Insights: Caching and Compress

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, deflate

I've got a PHP which automatically compresses a CSS file.
It's name is `minified.css.php`

For everyone who is interested, this is how it looks like:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    ob_start("compress");

    function compress( $minify ) {
        // remove comments
        $minify = preg_replace( "/\/\*.+?\*\//", '', $minify );

        // remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc.
        $minify = str_replace( array("\rn", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $minify );

        // brackets
        $minify = str_replace( array(' {', '{ '), '{', $minify );
        $minify = str_replace( array(' }', '} '), '}', $minify );
        $minify = str_replace( array(' (', '( '), '(', $minify );
        $minify = str_replace( array(' )', ') '), ')', $minify );

        // (semi)colons
        $minify = str_replace( array(' ;', '; '), ';', $minify );
        $minify = str_replace( array(' :', ': '), ':', $minify );

        return $minify;
    }

    /* css files for combining */
    include(getcwd().'/style.css');

    ob_end_flush();
```

But Google wants it to be deflated and also add a expiration date. The relevant section in my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    Addtype font/truetype .ttf

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Which lines do I have to add to make the `minified.css.php` cacheable + expiration date?

Edit: Used the header of `minified.css.php` to enable caching.

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=29030400");
header("Cache-Control: public", false);
```

**But still, the compressing issue exists.**

Answer (score 2):

It is a php file, just add the MIME type for php:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  application/x-httpd-php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresByType application/x-httpd-php "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Maybe because of the .css.php?

Comment: I saw this later that you are setting a header `header('Content-type: text/css');` so, the MIME type is `text/css`. In this case, the directive `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css` should  suffice. What is the Content-Length of this file? mod_deflate won't compress the file, if it is too small.

Comment: The `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE txt/css` is already there, inside the `.htaccess`. Plus, the original CSS file which is being minified by the PHP has more than 2000 lines, so I think the size isn't a problem. PageSpeed Insights doesn't complain when I'm using the regular `style.css`. It just tells me to compress when I'm using the `minified.css.php`.